# Oracle APEX application without workspace

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm new to Oracle APEX and I'm trying to understand the platform architecture.
I've been reading different tutorials and as per my understanding an application is always associated with a workspace. 
Now, at work, I've been told that in the Development and in the Testing environments we do have workspaces. But we don't have workspace in Production environment (to avoid doing development in PROD). For deployments we need to access through the back end and run the scripts in the database directly.

Could it be possible that there are applications without an associated workspace?

I understand that we may not be granted access to the workspace, but that it doesn't exist at all, that's a whole other story. But again, I'm a beginner and I don't have much knowledge of APEX, so maybe I'm wrong.

I'll appreciate any clarifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applications will always need to be associated with a workspace. Don't be confused between the concept of workspace and App Builder. Workspaces always exist. The App Builder may or may not be available depending on how APEX was installed. For PROD deployments, it is as you said, generally encouraged to install the "runtime-only" environment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really made everything more clear to me. Now I understand that there is indeed a workspace, it's just that the development environment is not available, what makes totally sense. But the affirmation "there is no workspace" was indeed wrong.

Comment: Good to hear. Thanks for the feedback.